# Jersey REST API request not working

Tags: rest, jersey, jersey-client

This is the first time I am working with Web Service, Jersey , Jackson and REST API.
I have gone through some basics of the Web Service, Jersey, Jackson and REST API.

I have developed a sample project using Netbeans IDE.

When I call my REST API from my browser I am getting the following Error which I figured out using developer tools.

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/ImageShowcase/v1/user/login

Request Method:GET

Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080

The following is the error which I got in Tomcat 7 Log

**SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sample.jersey.app.MyServlet**

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate API Key and Secret. Cannot initialize application. Please make sure your API Key and Secret is stored in ~/.stormpath/apiKey.properties**

This my project structure :

[image]

In the controller package I have the following code User.java
    package com.sample.controller;

```
import com.sample.model.UserModel;
import com.sample.pojo.UserCredentials;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/user")
public class User {

    @Path("/login")
    @POST 
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response UserAuthentication(UserCredentials user) {


        String output = "{\"username\":\"xyz\",\"password\":\"abc\"}";

        UserModel userAuthentication = new UserModel();
        if(userAuthentication.AuthenticateUser(user))
            return Response.status(201).entity(output).build();
        else
            return Response.status(201).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

The following is my JerseyClient Code

```
package com.sample.jerseyclient;


import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            System.out.println("Client started");
        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/ImageShowcase/v1/user/login");

        String input = "{\"username\":\"demo\",\"password\":\"demo\"}";
        // POST method
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        // check response status code
        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

        // display response
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... ");
        System.out.println(output + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
}
```

Following is my UserModel where I am implementing my bussiness logic (database etc).

```
package com.sample.model;

import com.sample.pojo.UserCredentials;
import java.sql.*;

public class UserModel {

    public boolean AuthenticateUser(UserCredentials user) {
        Database db = new Database();
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            String username = user.getUsername();
            String password = user.getPassword();
            ResultSet rs;

            con = db.getConnection();
            if (con != null) {
                String selectQuery_UserDetails = "SELECT NAME,PASSWORD FROM USER WHERE NAME=? AND PASSWORD = ?";

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery_UserDetails);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

                rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectQuery_UserDetails);
                if (rs != null) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            db.closeConnection(con);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my POJO class for user credentials:

```
package com.sample.pojo;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class UserCredentials {

    @JsonProperty
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty
    private String password;


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong here.
Another thing I want to know is, whether the structure I am using is correct or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question. Start with the relevant code from `com.sample.jersey.app.MyServlet`. `~/.stormpath/apiKey.properties` is a hint for Stormpath, but nothing to see here. Btw, request method is actually POST not GET

Comment: That is the part where I am confused and don't know why it is showing like this even though I did not have such package.
Is this the problem related to Build , because before implementing my solution , I executed a sample application , which contained this package.
Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Another thing I want to know is how to run JerseyClient.
Can I use postman to test all these api's?

Comment: @zyexal : I am using POSTMAN now to test my API and I am getting 415 unsupported media type, for the same above code in new and different project

Comment: I recreated the project with the same code and it is working for me.
I think there was a problem during build.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a fairly old thread, I still felt to put in my thoughts if it may benefit any one.

Ensure the following is set in web.xml

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```